# Azure DevOps IOS build issue: error: We stopped hearing from agent Hosted Agent

Tags: flutter, azure, macos, azure-devops, cicd

I am trying to set up CI/CD Pipeline for the flutter ios app using Azure DevOps, somehow I am getting this error multiple times exactly around 1 hour and 14 minutes of compilation time.

**Note: 1. I have already increased the default timer from 60 min to 120 min, so that's not a problem.
2. I was facing a similar issue in GCP for the android version of the same app, Our app was too big, and the default VM configuration wasn't enough, I bumped it up to a VM with 8GB ram and it worked!!!, is there a way to bump up the Machine VM configuration in Azure Pipeline the same way?**

```
We stopped hearing from the agent Hosted Agent. Verify the agent machine is running and has a healthy network connection. Anything that terminates an agent process[enters image description here][1] starves it for CPU, or blocks its network access can cause this error. For more information, see: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=846610
Pool: Azure Pipelines
```